# MySQL keeps restarting due to running out of memory

Tags: mysql, database, memory

how can we prevent this from happening? it generally causes down time of about 30 minutes, which is extremely disruptive for service...

Comment: Can you give a bit more data about the problem? Logs and system setup would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL tag, so I'm guessing MySQL.  I've had that FUBAR an InnoDB database before.

Sounds like you do not have your configuration optimized at all.  Tuning is going to be specific to your database engine.  I provided some general recommendations in the post linked below, which would apply to you as well.

[How do I set my.cnf in Mysql so that there are no limits to connections?](https://serverfault.com/questions/119468/how-do-i-set-my-cnf-in-mysql-so-that-there-are-no-limits-to-connections/119550#119550)

Comment: +1 because you're wearing a bow tie in your gravatar (and because it's a good answer)